# Attribute error in web scraping python bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have written a python code for web scraping and its seems everything fine but when I run this code I receive an "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'" so please have a look and guide  me on how can I fix this type of error. thanks

here is my code:

```
import pandas
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-search/Orlando_FL/dom-1'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
linklist = []
urls = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'jsx-4195823209 photo-wrap')
for url in urls:
    for link in url.find_all('a', href=True):
        linklist.append('https://www.realtor.com' + link['href'])
#print(linklist)

testurl = 'https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-detail/127-W-Wallace-St_Orlando_FL_32809_M62756-65861'

r = requests.get(testurl, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
address = soup.find('div', class_='jsx-1959108432 address-section').h1.text
print(address)
name = soup.find('a', class_ = 'jsx-725757796 agent-name').text.strip()
print(street)
```

Comment: when i execute it, i got result as address 127 W Wallace St, Orlando, FL, 32809
and name as Mark Ramey. is this your extected result by the way no error found. One this in last line print may be name.

Comment: @Samsul Islam thanks but why result not showing in my case?

Comment: I guess `name = soup.find(...)` should instead be `street = soup.find(...)`, but otherwise the code works for me too. What are you versions (python/bs4)?

Comment: It seems results are inconsistent, I managed to have an error too. The request doesn't return the same thing every time. Maybe class names varies `jsx-1959108432 ` is probably not something you want in your selector.

Comment: @SamsulIslam could you please guide me how can I find exact class name to extract accurat data as you said result are inconsistent.

Comment: You need to find class names or ID that are consistent over different pages / page load. It will in this case probably need more complex item access. For example, you probably wont be able to access the agent's name directly and will need to instead access parents of it.

Comment: Also, there is an anti-bot on this website, and it sometimes return an error : `As you were browsing something about your browser made us think you were a bot. There are a few reasons this might happen:` which can also be the reason why we get inconsistent results.

Comment: Maybe they have this because they have an API, so they want to "force you" to use the api. Have a look at the network requests you'll see that most of the data is retrieved from this API : https://www.realtor.com/api/v1/

Comment: what is `street` ?

Comment: When I run this I get `127 W Wallace St, Orlando, FL, 32809
Mark Ramey` Isn't that what you are looking for? I used `print(name)`

Answer (score 0):

The likely issue is with either of these lines:

```
address = soup.find('div', class_='jsx-1959108432 address-section').h1.text
name = soup.find('a', class_ = 'jsx-725757796 agent-name').text.strip()
```

You're trying to access attributes of an object that you have no guarantee is not a **NoneType** every time the script runs

You have alternatives such as using a try/except block like this

```
try:
    address = soup.find('div', class_='jsx-1959108432 address-section').h1.text
except Exception as e:
    print('The following error occurred getting the text from the address: %r', e)
```

This method of exception handling is generic; you can be more specific like this:

```
try:
    address = soup.find('div', class_='jsx-1959108432 address-section').h1.text
except AttributeError:
    print('Could not get text from address')
```

Essentially you need some validation for things such as:

- What if the request fails?
- What if the classnames on the web page change/don't exist

Comment: Using this strategy will fail to retrieve information even when it exists. That's probably not the goal here. Using these varying `jsx` codes is not what should be done here.

Comment: @cglacet - Yes but that's not what we're being asked. There are numerous possible improvements to the script; my answer outlines handling when there's no result returned. It's up to the OP to work his way up the script to fix/improve other parts

Comment: I think everyone knows how to use `try/except` so I don't see the point sorry. Also the question asks for a fix. Not how to ignore the problem.